# Error when sending email through Sendgrid API

Tags: python, django, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

On my production server I am getting the error below

"**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'apikey'"

The same code on the development server is working.

My production server is running gunicorn and I have added the environment variable SENDGRID_API_KEY to the gunicorn.service file. I have restarted gunicorn and nginx. I can see that the environment variable is loaded.

The method I am calling to send the email is below:

```
def sendtestemail(to):
    sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey=os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
    from_email = Email("<myemail>@<mydomain>.com")
    to_email = Email(to)
    subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun"
    content = Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with Python")
    mail = Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)
    response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
    return [response.status_code, response.body, response.headers]
```

Comment: Where is your `SENDGRID_API_KEY` located??? I pretty much already know the answer, but just wanna make sure before answering.

Comment: Hi, it is in the gunicorn.service file and I have set it with "-e SENDGRID_API_KEY=<THE API KEY> . I know that might not be ideal, but just trying to get that to work as it doesn't if I try to reference a file.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about that setup, but the way I do it is by adding my `SENDGRID_API_KEY` into my settings file, `from projectroot.settings import SENDGRID_API_KEY`, and then add that variable to your `sg` object. I'm guessing here that os.environ isn't getting your variable with the way you have it set. That dictionary key certainly isn't in my setup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have just tried it that way as well, but unfortunately, I get the same error.

Comment: I have found that the development server is on version 5.6.0 and the production server is on 6.0.4. I think it is related to this. If I change the argument name "apikey" to "api_key" then I get a different error. The error I then get is "Object of type 'Email' is not JSON serializable" which suggests it is accepting the first line of code. It might be that this function is out of date, but I have checked the documentation at https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/v3-python-code-example/ and it is as I have written. I have contacted SendGrid support to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue originates from a breaking change introduced in sendgrid 6.0. The keyword argument for `apikey` has been removed and replaced with a positional argument.

To resolve with your example, remove `apikey=` from your arguments, and just pass the api_key as a positional argument.

```
    sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
```

This can be a bit confusing when looking back at all previous examples as well as GitHub documentation, but [this example on the official documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/v3-python-code-example/) does get it right.

---

Note: I do see that at the time of asking your question, you were indeed following the documentation I linked above correctly. There are a [few issues opened](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/issues/804) where the documentation remained inaccurate for quite some time, but was resolved back in may.

Comment: Thanks, this is an old question, but I believe that I realized that the API had changed in that version and the documentation was not updated. I will mark this as the answer.